# Attaching an event handler

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a event handler called some-handler and a event called someevent following works when doing it in javascript,

```
window.onsomeevent = space.some_handler;
```

I have been googling for nearly an hour but I can not find how to do this in clojurescript?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a snippet to add a mousedown listener to window. Look here for the other google closure event types: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_events_eventtype.js.source.html

```
(ns example
  (:require
   [goog.dom :as dom]
   [goog.events :as events]))

(def w (dom/getWindow))
(events/listen w (.-MOUSEDOWN events/EventType) #(js/alert "Handle Mouse Down"))
```

Comment: The syntax for accessing javascript properties may have changed, I am just starting with ClojureScript. Today, I needed a small change in te code above: (.-MOUSEDOWN events/EventType)